# NodeJS - Running server app on two IP addresses

Tags: node.js, windows, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm running a nodejs app on two different IP addresses on a windows server.

What I've done is using my express app listening to two IPs like following:

```
http.createServer(expressApp).listen(5000, xxx.xxx.xxx.aaa, function() {
    //callback
});

http.createServer(expressApp).listen(5000, xxx.xxx.xxx.bbb, function() {
    //callback
});
```

Now what is happening is I'm getting a snapshot data which seems to have got stuck at some point. While one of the interface is working perfectly, The other one does not get the data from mongoDB correctly. It's like it's working on some kind of cached copy of data. Even the time returned from the server is stopping.

Every new refresh on the page gets the correct time but not the correct mongoDB data.

I've also tried removing the IP, tried putting 0.0.0.0 and starting two nodejs processes listening on different IPs.
None of these are working.

Answer (score 0):

All of those approaches should work, and if you are getting http responses then it seems like they are.   If you're having problems with another part of your program, it's likely that's where the issue is.